# StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, ejb

I'm trying to make a REST API using JPA/EJB, but I get an error when I execute my code and I try to test the functionality using Advanced Rest Client(Chrome)
It seems like my DAO isn't injected the correct way? When trying to execute the code I get a nullpointerexception (always on the method (getAuteurs) itself)

My code:

```
@Path("auteurs")
public class AuteurRestController {


@EJB
private AuteurDAO service;

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Auteur> getAuteurs(){
return service.getAll(); 
}
}



@Stateless
public class AuteurDAO implements DAO<Auteur> {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public AuteurDAO(){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
}
@Override
public List<Auteur> getAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Auteur> cq = cb.createQuery(Auteur.class);
    cq.from(Auteur.class);
    TypedQuery<Auteur> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

My Error :

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service()        for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at RestControllers.AuteurRestController.getAuteurs(AuteurRestController.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service:

```
@EJB
private AuteurDAO service;
```

does not get injected for some reason thus when you call `service.getAll()` you get a `NullPointerException` because `service` is `null`. Check your configuration.